# Shrew soft VPN Auto reconnect

Tags: vpn

I am evaluating Shrew Soft VPN client and it's working well for me on Windows 7 x64, where other clients have troubles. Thanks for that.

The problem is that my VPN connection breaks periodically - sometimes every couple of hours and sometimes as often as every few minutes. This is just how my gateway is - it is not VPN client's fault. I just re-connect and keep working.

With other clients, I am able to set up automatic re-connection.

Why doesn't Shrew Soft VPN client have an option to automatically re-connect disconnected sessions ? I understand that I can do it manually, but that is quite disruptive. If there's no way to achieve auto-reconnection in the current version, then consider it a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Shrew Soft VPN client supports auto reconnect since version 2.2 (latest) - see announcement from 2013-07-01 at https://www.shrew.net/home

Or there can be done workaround for that for another versions using this tool: https://github.com/CamW/shrew-reconnect

But, in short, Shrew Soft VPN client is very problematic when connection is unstable and I do not recommend to use it. It seams like a dead project which is maybe not actively developed anymore.